# How to access setter from nested object in android?

Tags: java, android, nested, retrofit, retrofit2

I wanna ask something, I want to set the "Agama" with inputted Edit text. But, it turns out an error like this:
[image]

In my Activity, I'm using spinner to get the agama values:

```
spAgama = findViewById(R.id.spfagama);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterAgama = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(TambahDataKeluarga.this,R.array.agama, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapterAgama.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spAgama.setAdapter(adapterAgama);
```

How can I set my spinner value into setAgama?
Here's my familylistresponse.java;

```
package com.example.cobaakses.cobaarrayretrofit;

import com.example.cobaakses.Agama;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class familylistresponse {

    @SerializedName("noPegawai")
    private String noPegawai;

    @SerializedName("date_otor")
    private Object dateOtor;

    @SerializedName("keterangan")
    private String keterangan;

    @SerializedName("tgl_Lahir")
    private String tglLahir;

    @SerializedName("nama")
    private String nama;

    @SerializedName("agama")
    private Agama agama;

    @SerializedName("statusNikah")
    private String statusNikah;

    @SerializedName("tempatLahir")
    private String tempatLahir;

    @SerializedName("id")
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("golDarah")
    private String golDarah;

    public void setNoPegawai(String noPegawai){
        this.noPegawai = noPegawai;
    }

    public String getNoPegawai(){
        return noPegawai;
    }

    public void setDateOtor(Object dateOtor){
        this.dateOtor = dateOtor;
    }

    public Object getDateOtor(){
        return dateOtor;
    }


    public void setKeterangan(String keterangan){
        this.keterangan = keterangan;
    }

    public String getKeterangan(){
        return keterangan;
    }


    public void setTglLahir(String tglLahir){
        this.tglLahir = tglLahir;
    }

    public String getTglLahir(){
        return tglLahir;
    }

    public void setNama(String nama){
        this.nama = nama;
    }

    public String getNama(){
        return nama;
    }

    public void setAgama(Agama agama){
        this.agama = agama;
    }

    public Agama getAgama(){
        return agama;
    }

    public void setStatusNikah(String statusNikah){
        this.statusNikah = statusNikah;
    }

    public String getStatusNikah(){
        return statusNikah;
    }

    public void setTempatLahir(String tempatLahir){
        this.tempatLahir = tempatLahir;
    }

    public String getTempatLahir(){
        return tempatLahir;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setGolDarah(String golDarah){
        this.golDarah = golDarah;
    }

    public String getGolDarah(){
        return golDarah;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return
                "familylistresponse{" +
                        ",id = '" + id + '\'' +
                        ",date_otor = '" + dateOtor + '\'' +
                        ",agama = '" + agama + '\'' +
                        ",tgl_Lahir = '" + tglLahir + '\'' +
                        ",nama = '" + nama + '\'' +
                        ",keterangan = '" + keterangan + '\'' +
                        ",tempatLahir = '" + tempatLahir + '\'' +
                        "noPegawai = '" + noPegawai + '\'' +
                        ",golDarah = '" + golDarah + '\'' +
                        ",statusNikah = '" + statusNikah + '\'' +
                        "}";
    }
}
```

and here's my Agama.java:

```
package com.example.cobaakses;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Agama{

    @SerializedName("id_Agama")
    private String idAgama;

    @SerializedName("agama")
    private String agama;

    public void setIdAgama(String idAgama){
        this.idAgama = idAgama;
    }

    public String getIdAgama(){
        return idAgama;
    }

    public void setAgama(String agama){
        this.agama = agama;
    }

    public String getAgama(){
        return agama;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return 
            "Agama{" + 
            "id_Agama = '" + idAgama + '\'' + 
            ",agama = '" + agama + '\'' + 
            "}";
        }
}
```

And also, whenever I try to input the data to the database, the data is not inserted into the database (I'm using retrofit btw) :( please anyone help me to solve this problem. Thank You

Comment: I don't know what kind of object "f" is, but the error is telling you that setAgama needs an Agama object as parameter, and you are sending it a String. You should do something like f.setAgama(new Agama(stringValue))

Comment: @Lenin f is for `familylistresponse f = new familylistresponse();`. And f.setAgama(newAgama(stringValue)) also give me an error like this https://imgur.com/a/AxCc46T . Also, I wrote this too "
            `f.setAgama(agamas.setAgama(valueAgama));`" which valueAgama is a string to get value from agamaspinner

Comment: The string as parameter to Agama was as example. It didn't work because you didn't defined a constructor that accepts a String, so you need to first create the Agama object and then set the String

Comment: @Lenin okay, it didn't show any error anymore, but why it's not stored to my database server even the value readable. will it be a problem because of the nested object JSON?

Comment: You are just using creating objects with that classes, and objects only live in memory. If you want to save it you should set it explicitly. I don't see server things in that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setAgama function in familylistresponse receives an Agama object so you need to create an Agama object first

```
Agama agama = new Agama()
```

now you need to set to that Agama object the string you want from spinner

```
agama.setAgama(sp.getSelectedItem().toString().trim())
```

Now your agama is ready to be set to familylistresponse

```
f.setAgama(agama)
```

Try to use better names for variables because you will have some trouble later understanding what you did when app gets bigger. Also, check that you have a function setAgama in both classes. You should name it differently in Agama class, because you have an Agama object that has an agama String inside. Maybe you can define the class as AgamaObject and have an argument called name inside, that would be the name of that Agama object